# symfony 3.4 cache problem on nginx server

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, caching, debian

I'm actually building a nginx server on debian 8 to deploy symfony 3.4 project.
All is ready and the welcome page appear but.. the code edited doesn't appear.
I mean, if I change the index's content, the welcome page will still the same.
In my opinion it's a cache problem, it may come from nginx conf or php7.1-fpm, I don't know it' my first time on it.

If you already fix this problem or even if you have an idea thanks to leave a comment ;)

Comment: Did you clear the Symfony cache after editing your code?

Comment: Yea I constantly clear the sf cache and restart nginx and php-fpm service

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted the Symfony cache folder ?
A good pratice would be to deploy your app via a manager (eg : https://deployer.org/)

Comment: Yea I constantly clear the sf cache and restart nginx and php-fpm service, ok but this time I don't have the choice :/

Comment: Humm, have you tried from another device/browser ? If you have cleared the SF cache, it may be your browser cache :-/ (it happens in dev)